# Qué palabra puede utilizarse para una persona que tiene opiniones contradictorias constantemente?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Estuve buscando y un sitio sugiere voluble

> El vocablo latino volubĭlis llegó al castellano como voluble. Este adjetivo hace referencia a aquello que carece de constancia o que se vuelve con facilidad hacia sus alrededores.
>
> Voluble: El término suele vincularse a la persona que cambia de
>   opinión, conducta, actitud o actividad con frecuencia

[Voluble](https://definicion.de/voluble/)

pero esta palabra parece tener un significado más amplio y según otros sitios hasta distinto:

> [persona, cosa] Que cambia fácil o frecuentemente de manera de ser.

[Voluble](https://www.google.com/search?ei=7qXWXcLDMoXG5OUPgoi5sAg&q=voluble%20significado&oq=voluble%20significado&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i324i70i249j0l2j0i22i30l7.16000.18665..19339...0.3..0.209.2133.6j12j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i131j0i67j0i70i249j0i10.YLcXdOirx8E&ved=0ahUKEwjC8r2ryPvlAhUFI7kGHQJEDoYQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Existe alguna alternativa más puntual, más específica? O alternativa siquiera?

Comment: A mi me parece que *voluble* está bien, aunque me gusta más *veleta*, como dice @user2325442 en su respuesta, que suena más coloquial. O también podría ser [inconstante](https://dle.rae.es/inconstante)

Comment: *Voluble* no significa que alguien siempre lleva el contrario, solo que se cambia de idea fácilmente. Yo diría que la palabra sería *desafiante* u *oposicionista*.

Comment: @nopaltepec pero la pregunta no apunta a alguien que lleva la contraria, sino a alguien que tiene opiniones contradictorias entre sí. Ahora que estoy pensando una palabra que iría bien sería incoherente.

Comment: Cuánta razón tienes, @Pablo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alguien con opiniones (y posiciones) cambiantes también puede ser designado como

> **veleta** (ver [fuente](https://dle.rae.es/veleta))
>
> 4. m. y f. Persona inconstante y mudable.

PD: Además de otros sinónimos, como *veleidoso*, *ligero*, *variable*, *antojadizo*, *caprichoso* o *cambiante* ([ver mas](https://servicios.elpais.com/diccionarios/sinonimos-antonimos/veleidoso))

Answer (score 0):

"Veleta" me parece bien, pero lo conocía más como una "idea veleta", según esa definición de veleta como persona por acá sería: "volteretas" o alguien que se "da vuelta la chaqueta" o que "va **a**donde el sol más calienta el sol" por conveniencia o para no salir perjudicado.

> DARSE VUELTA LA CHAQUETA arrepentirse, echarse para atrás, irse al bando contrario. Algunos sinónimos , palabras o expresiones similares pueden ser renegar, pasarse al bando opositor, arrepentirse

> Estar donde calienta el sol: Ser oportunista; estar en lugar privilegiado; ubicarse donde se está mejor; arrimarse a los privilegios y al bienestar;
> cf. **veleta**;
> "los políticos hablan de las miserias del pueblo, pero ellos están siempre donde calienta el sol"

Si tiene una conducta dual o patológica se diría algo como "incoherente".

Para mí alguien que incurre en opiniones contradictorias es contradictorio/a, aunque por acá se diría junto a la palabra persona e inconsistente junto a planteamiento, discurso, etc:

> Contradictorio: 2. [persona] Que se contradice o incurre en contradicciones.

Si esa contradicción es por falta de carácter sería una persona débil, por falta de constancia: inconstante.

Si es porque es fácil de convencer sin más, dócil o maleable:

> maleable: 3. adj. Fácil de convencer o persuadir.